# Interpret the terms in Strang's second lemma

Tags: sobolev-spaces, estimation

The second lemma of Strang states that for a certain choice of $V_h$, $a$, $u$ and $f$ there exists a $c>0$ such that

$$||u-u_h|| \leq c \left(\inf_{v\in V_h} ||u-v|| + \sup_{v\in V_h} \frac{|a(u,v)-(f,v)|}{||v||}\right)$$

where $V_h \not\subset H_0^1(\Omega)$.

The first term on the right side is called *approximation error*, the second one *consistence error*. What is the motivation of these names, i.e. why are the terms named as they are?

Comment: This is the first Google hit for "second Strang lemma" but the question is not even posted with correct notation and sufficient background.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The approximation error comes from the  discretization of *the function space*; it has nothing to do with equation we are solving. This error is the distance from $u$ to the space $V_h$. There is no way for $u_h$ to be closer to $u$ than this number, because $u_h\in V_h$ by construction.

The consistency error comes from the discretization of *the equation*. Originally it was: 
$a(u,v)=f(v)$ for all $v\in H_0^1$. When working with elements $V_h$ we actually use discrete analogs of $a$ and $f$, which should have been called $a_h$ and $f_h$ in your equation. In general, the exact solution of the continuous equation is not a solution of the discrete equation. That is, $a_h(u,v)-f_h(v)$ is not necessarily zero for all $v\in V_h$. This is what the consistency error measures; it is about the (imperfect) consistency between the continuous and discrete equations.

In a summary:

- The approximation error measures the failure of our finite-dimensional function space to capture the exact solution $u$.
- The consistency error measures the failure of the continuous solution $u$ to satisfy the discrete equation.